# Responsive image height inside Bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have no idea why this is such a struggle. I want to place an image inside a container. That image should be responsive, meaning when the column gets smaller in width, the image should also get smaller. It does that now, but it maintains the height, meaning it will look stretched.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmZKyM

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Left column</p>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Right column</p>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x400" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not know the aspect ratio of the image (in this case I do), so I cannot achieve this with the `padding-bottom` trick (normally used for images).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't use `max-height` to the `img`? :)

Comment: @Troyer What would I set the max-height to?

Comment: I would create a img container with a div, but you can set it on the img, at your choice.

Comment: @Troyer I'll ask again: What do I set the max-height to?

Comment: change `max-width: 100%;` to `width: 100%;` and also add `height: 100%;`

Comment: @AlaaMh `height: 100%` would screw it up.

Comment: I did check codepen before, check updated codepen http://codepen.io/AlaaMh/pen/PmjzRP

Comment: @AlaaMh Oh that's odd, it didn't work for me when I tried. Codepen is so bad at times. I don't even know when it updates the DOM. Make an answer and I'll mark is as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem buddy, you are welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `max-width: 100%;` to `width: 100%;`  also change `height: auto;` to `height: 100%;`

Answer (score -1):

If the container should have a fixed height, then give it an ID (or a class) and change the .img-responsive restrictions the other way around eg

```
.container {
height: 600px;
}


/*And then change */
.container .img-responsive {
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}  

/*To */
.container  .img-responsive {
display: block;
width: auto;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

Not sure how it will work with a mix of orientations but if they are floated it shouldnt really matter

Comment: They are not responsive and the container should not have a fixed height.